# How to define keyboard shortcut for "Save to your Music" Functionality for Spotify

Tags: applescript, spotify

I really love the Spotify app. When I like some songs on Spotify, I'm using ["Save to Your Music"](https://jumpshare.com/v/QsNQuZ8vwhSVXgu7Hjb4) to add songs to my Spotify library. But this requires switching applications and using the mouse, so I want to create a shortcut key to do this?

Is there any way to create something similar to [this idea](http://dailymactips.com/assign-the-spotify-or-rdio-playpause-action-to-a-keyboard-shortcut-using-automator/) which does "Save to Your Music"?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. How would this AppleScript differ from using "Save to your Music" in Spotify directly?

Comment: Oh, sorry about this. I will try to bind a shortcut key this AppleScript like this idea: http://dailymactips.com/assign-the-spotify-or-rdio-playpause-action-to-a-keyboard-shortcut-using-automator/

Also I will edit my question about your notice.

Comment: You can do this with the web-based version of Spotify. Will that work for you? The desktop client is about as unscriptable as any application gets (despite having a rather mediocre scripting dictionary).

Comment: I'm using desktop version of Spotify. So web-based solution does not work for me. :-/